# Finding a good fit for datapoints

Tags: interpolation, least-squares, data-analysis

for my project I found that my data roughly follows a certain shape. See below. (They are from three different but similar experiments.) I was wondering if any of you know a good fit. I already tried something like $f(x) = ax + b/x$, which is a hyperbola symmetric wrt the origin with asymptotes $y = ax$ (for $a > 0$) and $x = 0$. ($a$ and $b$ have to be fitted.)

However, with these $f$ I find the following fits:

[image] [image] [image]

It's good, but I believe it could be better. For example, the bottom bump shouldn't be as sharp. Also, I'd like to incorporate a second "bump".

I was wondering if any of you could recommend some functions which would work better. (One with (not too many) parameters which still need to be fitted.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|\log x|$ looks like that.  I'd start there.

Comment: Is it from physics, chemistry or ???

Comment: What about adding a cos(x) to the equation?

Comment: Try polynomial regression.

Comment: You can try different fits over different ranges. Do you have requirements on continuity and differentiability of the fit?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! Bravo for your judicious question.

Answer (score 1):

Without clue about the kind of physical model one can imagine a lot of models equations. For example the combination of a linear function with a damped sinusoidal function :

[image]

Even with a simple polynomial equation the fitting isn't worse than with the above more sophisticated model :

[image]